# Mysql query for an options table

Tags: mysql

Say I have one table called kitchens.

I have a second table called kitchen_options.

They are linked by kitchen_id.

A kitchen option could include say forks, plates, stoves.

Forks might be 1, plates 2, etc...

So some sample rows from the options table might look like:

```
1122 1
1122 2
1122 3
1123 1
1123 2
1124 3
1125 1
```

Say I want to get all kitchens that have forks AND plates (1 & 2).  So this should return 1122 and 1123 but NOT 1125.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not an efficient solution, but you could try:

```
select kitchen_id from kitchen_options
where kitchen_id in (select kitchen_id from kitchen_options where option = 1)
and kitchen_id in (select kitchen_id from kitchen_options where option = 2)
```

Comment: I like that!  Much better than my convoluted group/conditional sum/having idea...  I don't think this will be a huge performance hit because the option table is small and repeat queries are limited by the options selected.  Thank you very much!

Comment: Oops...turns out this did take a long time to execute (6 seconds).  Oh well...back to the drawing table.  Let me know if you have any other ideas.